# Snipping Tool doesn't prompt to save snips for certain window size (Windows 7 OS)

Tags: windows-7, windows

It seem to be something very recent and I can't figure out the cause. All the setting seem to be fine ("Prompt to save snips before exiting" is checked) and it does prompts for smaller window sizes, but it doesn't prompt when I select a wider snip, see gif below to illustrate the problem.

[image]

I've looked all over the net and haven't find anything similar. Saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/666627/windows-snipping-tool-highlights-the-wrong-area) post, but it wasn't useful. Also saw [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/506/free-windows-program-to-save-screenshots-on-key-press-immediately/) for alternatives, but I'm currently mainly interested to resolve this with Snipping Tool in particular.

I'm suspecting it maybe has to do something with my screens relatively high resolution (2560X1440) which is basically the main reason I want to capture a wider screen because the high resolution allows me to capture very large and detailed images.